# Laravel Paginate with Dynamic Method

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a REST API on Laravel. I currently have a Model ( Project ) which has 2 Dynamic Methods ( liveindexes and totalindexes ).

I want the API (/projects) to return the values of both those methods as well.

Project Controller

```
public function index()
{
     return Project::paginate();
}
```

Project Model

```
class Project extends Model
{
      protected $table = 'projects';

      protected $fillable = [
          'target'
      ];

      public function indexes()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('App\indexes','project_id','id');
      }

      public function totalindexes()
      {
          return $this->indexes()->count();
      }

      public function liveindexes()
      {
          return $this->indexes()->whereNotNull('anchor')->count();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include these items with your `Project` model, add them to your model's attributes, attributes are appended when to model is transformed into an array, or it's JSON form.

Add this to your code:

```
protected $appends = ['live_indexes', 'total_indexes'];

public function getLiveIndexesAttribute() {
    return $this->attributes['live_indexes'] = $this->liveIndexes();
} 

public function getTotalIndexes() {
    return $this->attributes['total_indexes'] = $this->totalindexes();
}
```

Comment: Tried this earlier. I get the following error
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on integer

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't realise you were counting the results. Check my updated answer

Comment: Worked! I was also able to achieve this using a closure function and withCount method. I still prefer your method.